# Lift If LocParam weird behaviour

Tags: lift

there is a `LocParam` `If` in lift framework. I'm wondering how it is meant to work. I have a simple menu of several items like this one:

```
val scanning = Menu(Loc("scanning","user" :: "scanning" :: Nil, 
S ? "scanning",LocGroup("user")))
```

which works just good, but when I add the `If`, there is weird behaviour. Firstly, the labels that are rendered in the `<a>` tag are not correct, they are taken from other `Menu` definitions. (Instead of the content of resource key "scanning", I see the contents of S ? "homepage"). Secondly, it just doesn't work, I assume, that the condition should redirect all accesses on /user/scanning to / since the condition is false everytime and it just lets the underlying snippet to render itself as if there wasn't any condition.

```
val scanning = Menu(Loc("scanning","user" :: "scanning" :: Nil, 
S ? "scanning",LocGroup("user"),If(() => false,() => RedirectResponse("/"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
() => false
```

That tells lift to never show your menu entry. So what you see is probably a different entry...

Comment: but I can see the entry, the href attribute still points to the same url and is acessible...